# How to skip a specific Div-Area while replacing text in DOM-Nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

*With this edit I try to be more specific with my question and add my last try to solve the problem:*
A browser add-on replaces some words on a website. This part works! Now there is some text which should not be replaced. This text is within the class "msg_content", e.g.

```
<span class="msg_content">don't replace my words</span>.
```

This part does the replacement-job and should skip elements with class "msg_content":

```
function replaceText (node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        //skip msg_content
        try {
          let note = document.querySelector('.msg_content');
          if (node == note){
            console.log("skip chat-area");
            return;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        let content = node.textContent;
        for (let [word, emoji] of langMap) {
          const regex = regexs.get(word);
          content = content.replace(regex, emoji);
        }
        node.textContent = content;
  }
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      replaceText(node.childNodes[i]);
    } 
  }
}
replaceText(document.body);
```

The replacement works finde, but it doesn't skip the msg_content.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your **exact** expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string is empty you can use `string.length` I added `string.trim()` in case the div contains any whitespace which is common in HTML:

```js
function replaceText (node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // My try to skip specific area here (doesn't work)
        //if (document.getElementById("chatBar")) {
        //  return;
        //}
        let content = node.textContent;
        if (!content.trim().length) return; // skip if content is empty
        for (let [word, emoji] of langMap) {
          const regex = regexs.get(word);
          content = content.replace(regex, emoji);
        }
        node.textContent = content;
  }
  else {
    // This node contains more than just text, call replaceText() on each
    // of its children.
    for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      replaceText(node.childNodes[i]);
    } 
  }
}
replaceText(document.body);
```

Comment: Ok, I was not quiet clear about what I want, sorry! The script goes through the whole page and replaces some words. Now there is a part of the page, where I don't want any replacements to be done. This part is anything which is within the <div id="chatBar"></div>. Or, if it's easier to manage anything within <ul class="chat_bar_list"></u>